# ActionScript: Correctly casting a bitmap to a class

Tags: actionscript

I have tree instance calling an iconFunction "getIconFromItem".

```
<mx:Tree dataProvider="{collection}" iconFunction="getIconFromItem" />
```

The getIconFromItem function is returning null even though the bitmap is not null.

```
    public function getIconFromItem(item:Object):Class {
    var result:Class = item.icon as Class ;
    return result ;
}
```

Setting a break point on the return result line reveals that item.icon is a bitmap and result is null.

Any ideas or pointers on how to successfully cast a bitmap as class so that the bitmap is returned as an icon?

Cheers

Keith

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `item.icon` is of type `Bitmap`, which is not extended from the type `Class`, but from `Object`.  Whenever you cast to a type that is not in the object's type hierarchy, `null` is returned.

You want to get the *class* of the icon, which will be instantiated by the tree control, not the icon itself, so you should change your function to

```
public function getIconFromItem(item:Object):Class {
     return item.icon.constructor as Class;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why a null is returned! Your suggestion causes a different error. 
_1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before class._ I'm doing some more research.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I mixed up languages a bit. I've removed the error, it should work now.

Comment: Found a way around it after studying [link]http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42 . The essence is embedded icons have auto generated 'classes'. The example by Ben Stucki has a static dictionary which is used to return the correct loader for the 'class'.

Comment: Ended up subclassing BitmapImage, added a set function to change the bitmapData and used this within an custom itemRenderer. Result ... dynamic loading of icons in a tree control.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was iconFunction expects a class. Each embedded image has a subclass automatically generated by the compiler. Thanks to @weltraumpirat for pointing me in the right direction :-)

The goal was to dynamically display icons in a tree class. It is possible to modify the class created by Ben Stucki (http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42) to work with the TreeItemRenderer.data object but this failed when I created a custom MXTreeItemRenderer.

Ended up creating a BitmapImage and a custom TreeItemRenderer which used a prefined iconBitmap attribute within a class to dynamically load icons.

```
package components
{

    import flash.display.BitmapData;

    import mx.core.mx_internal;

    import spark.core.IContentLoader;
    import spark.primitives.BitmapImage;

    public class RuntimeBitmapImage extends BitmapImage
    {
        public function RuntimeBitmapImage()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function set bitmapData(bitmapData:BitmapData):void
        {
            super.setBitmapData(bitmapData, false);
        }

    }
}    



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXTreeItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


            override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                super.data = value;

                if ( value != null ) {

                    if ( value.iconBitmap != null ) {
                        runtimeBitmapImage.bitmapData = value.iconBitmap.bitmapData ;
                    }

                } 


            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />            
        <s:State name="hovered" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>


    <s:HGroup left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" paddingTop="2" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:Rect id="indentationSpacer" width="{treeListData.indent}" percentHeight="100" alpha="0">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
        <potentiate:RuntimeBitmapImage id="runtimeBitmapImage" left="2" width="18" />
        <s:Label id="labelField" text="{treeListData.label}" paddingTop="2"/>
    </s:HGroup>

</s:MXTreeItemRenderer>
```